# Local user-friendly installation of MongoDB dependency

Tags: .net, mongodb, visual-studio, c#-4.0

I’m trying to make an application that uses mongoDB for saving data, but I have problem that user may not have mongoDB installed on his computer.

How can I make some user friendly installation process that checks if user has MongoDB installed and installs it if he doesn’t?

I’m building WPF app on .NET 6 and Visual Studio 2022

Comment: I would say, quite difficult. The Mongo service may have any name and may run on any port (not only 27017) or the MongoDB runs even on a different machine. I would suggest to put MongoDB into your "System Requirements and Prerequisites" document. You don't know the MongoDB user credentials anyway. The user has to specify the connection URI, that's not in your responsibility.